# linux LF is not working in my perl script

Tags: linux, perl

Even though I am using binmode to write a file I still see windows style LF.

```
# open the files
open (inFile, "<$inFileName") or die "can't open $inFileName: $!\n";
binmode inFile;
open (outFile, ">$outFileName");
binmode outFile;

# get the input file size
$fileSize = -s $inFileName;

# read in the file
sysread(inFile, $fileStr, $fileSize);

# calc the checksum
$strChecksum = unpack("%32C*", $fileStr);

$headerStr = pack(V4,$fileID, $fileFlags, $fileSize, $strChecksum);

print outFile "$headerStr$fileStr";

close inFile;
close outFile;
```

I expect linux style LFs in my binary file I see 0x0d 0x0a instead of 0x0a.
I am using activestate perl 5.16.3

Can anyone pls help me finding out why this binmode is not working?

Comment: If the input file has windows style EOLs then reading it in binmode will preserve them. Try reading the input file in text mode and writing the output file in binmode.

Answer (score 1):

You still have Windows line endings because you never change the line endings.

`binmode` on an input handle causes the contents of the file to be returned unchanged.

`binmode` on an output handle causes the contents of the scalar to be written unchanged.

If your output file contains CR LF, it's because your input file contains CR LF.

You are missing

```
$fileStr =~ s/\r//g;
```

Alternatively, just leave off the `binmode` on the input handle.

---

By the way, `sysread` isn't guaranteed to read the number of bytes you requested, so your usage of it is broken. Use

```
1 while sysread(inFile, $fileStr, 64*1024, length($fileStr));
```

or

```
{ local $/; $fileStr = <inFile>; }
```

---

By the way,

```
pack(V4, ...)
```

should be

```
pack('V4', ...)
```

Always use `use strict; use warnings;`!